# capturing and adjusting posted values in firebug

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, firebug

I'm debugging a form where the values aren't being reflected in the rails app. Is there a way in firebug to capture a post or put request, make some adjustments, and then 'replay' the request? I'm assuming there is but googling didn't give me so many good results.

thx

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) instead.

It doesn't have "replay" option, it just pops up a window on any request (after you activate it), you modify the values, and then press a button to actually perform a POST/PUT.

If the form doesn't disappear right away after you click, you may click multiple times and tamper the values on-the-fly each time.